# How can i run a command script by opening it in a terminal by clicking on it

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I can run a command from my terminal. Think as in : Terminal `# ls -l -> output` etc.
If I want to run a script I can drag it into the terminal or specify it's location like, `/usr/script` and run it.

But here is my question:
Is it possible and how can I run a command script by simply clicking on it on my desktop? I already set it to be opened by the terminal application but when I click it it does not run.

The command I want to run is nwipe.

This is my script:

```
.#!bin/bash

sudo nwipe
```

(ignore the dot in front of #).

PS nwipe does not run without sudo.

Ubuntu Xenial 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Easy, you are using sudo in a non interactive shell. It can't do anything since it wants to start a interactive shell but can't.

Also nwipe has no GUI so your command would do, uhh, nothing? Since it would open a terminal use the command and close it again.

What you actually need is a .desktop file that runs your command and leaves the terminal open. Don't forget to make it executable or rather "make it a trusted file"

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=nwipe
Comment=RUN MY WONDERFUL NWIPE
Exec=sudo nwipe
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

Comment: It would be better to use gksudo because then you would not need to leave the terminal open.

Comment: It's a terminal program like aptitude, there is no gui to start.

Comment: Ok sorry about the confusion

Comment: if i run the command: "sudo nwipe" in ubuntu i get a gui inisde a terminal. with simple keyboard controls to select and start wiping disk.

Comment: I know HALP, that's exactly what I said in my recent comments. Have you tried my solution, it should do exactly what you wish for.